# Masking OS / PC name in Python

Tags: python, windows

I'm using various commands in Python to get the PC names:

```
platform.node()
socket.gethostname()
os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']
```

Is it possible to "mask" or "spoof" your PC name so that these commands get a pre-defined name? (not the real PC name)

Comment: Please explain the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I'm using SMTP to send emails and don't want to pass my real PC name as a header

Comment: Then we have a typical [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Please edit and ask the real question!

Comment: What @KlausD. said. This question has nothing with python to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [SMTPLIB doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) :

> class **smtplib.SMTP**(host='', port=0, **local_hostname**=None, [timeout, ]source_address=None) :
>
> …
>
> If specified, **local_hostname** is used as the FQDN of the local host in the HELO/EHLO command. Otherwise, the local hostname is found using socket.getfqdn()